# Why did my title and other text boxes disappear when I resized the layout in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, layouts, text, title

I had finished building a nice layout with my maps, inserts, scale bar, and text boxes. However, when I changed the layout from landscape to portrait all of the map elements such as the text boxes and title vanished.  It is as though they were deleted or are simply floating somewhere off of the view.

Is there any way to recover them?

Comment: Maybe your map frame is just drawing on top of the map elements?  In the layout view, Click your map frame.  Right click and choose Order, then choose Send to Back.  Did your other elements now appear?

Comment: Or they could have simply shifted off the rotated page and they are in fact still in your layout? Zoom out to confirm.

Comment: Edit/Select All Elements/Zoom to selected should find all layout elements.